# Unable to print Interval Using Vectors in CPP

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

```cpp
using namespace std;

void print(std::vector<int,int> a)
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    
    {
       std::cout << "Original " << a[i];
    }
}

int main()
{

    vector<pair<int, int> >a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        a.push_back({ x,y });
     }
    print(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void print(std::vector<pair<int, int>> a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "Original " << a[i].first << "," << a[i].second;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int, int> > a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        a.push_back({x, y});
    }
    print(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH BRO FOR HELPING ME REGARDING THIS

Answer (score 0):

Your `print()` function should have the signature of `void print(vector<pair<int,int>> a)`.

In your `print()` function, you are trying to print `a[i]` directly, but `a[i]` is a `pair<int,int>`. You need to print each value in the `pair` individually. For example:

```
cout << "Original " << a[i].first << "," << a[i].second;
```

Comment: Passing by const ref is even better.